# Batch Flip Raster

Tags: arcpy, raster, batch

I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight as to how to batch flip a raster data set in arcpy?

I know the code and syntax for flipping a single raster but am having trouble figuring out how to batch flip the raster in arcpy (there are many rasters so renaming in the batch processing interface would be too time consuming).